# Windows 10 to android bluetooth, windows say paired and connected, android says paired but cant connect

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, android, bluetooth

Trying to link s20+5g to windows 10 desktop via bluetooth. Have tried this on two different machines and received the same result. They pair fine, then when I try to connect them windows say they connected, but the phone says it cannot connect and will not do anything with the bluetooth connection. Is there any settings I can change on the phone (in the developer settings maybe?) or the desktop to try and fix this? I do not have root access on the phone (US snapdragon unfortunately). The bluetooth driver is updated to the latest version, and I have updated windows to the latest version in my attempts to fix this.

Comment: For what purpose do you establish the connection between Smartphone and PC?

Comment: @Robert To answer your question, for me I would play audio on my phone output through headphone jack into my computer for listening to music when streaming. You don't want the music picked up on stream. A lot of new phones don't have headphone jacks so can use Bluetooth to accomplish the same thing. FWIW, I have the same problem on S21+.